# comparing two arbitary files with the internal gitkraken diff tool?

Tags: git, diff, gitkraken

gitkraken hasn't detected a file has been moved and renamed. In any case, Is there any way to diff between two arbitary files, without using an external diff tool?

Answer (score 1):

GitKraken (and any other git GUI for that matter) will show diff of the same file. That's the workflow when using git (that includes file renaming and content changing).
It makes no sense for any git GUI to show differences between 2 random files.
You can use many tools to get diff between 2 sources (such as [Diff Checker](https://www.diffchecker.com/), [DiffNow](https://www.diffnow.com/), etc.)

However, if you had a file that was moved and renamed and now GitKraken does not detect that it is the same file, the easiest solution IMO is:

- Make a copy of the renamed file and paste it to its former location
  and name.
- Merge your branches and solve the conflict on the copied version.
- Override the renamed file with the copied version.